# "block checkbox_widget" draw a checkbox

Tags: twig, symfony4

I'm customizing the checkbox_widget in one form. In the template that draw this form I have:

```
{%- block checkbox_widget -%}
{% set emailmult1a00 = app.session.get('emailmult1a00') %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ emailmult1a00 }}" />
{%- endblock checkbox_widget -%}
```

It works fine in my form, but it draws a checkbox in place where the block is in the template.

How can I delete this checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem using a separate Template:

```
{# templates/form/fields.html.twig #}
{%- block checkbox_widget -%}
{% set emailmult1a00 = app.session.get('emailmult1a00') %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ emailmult1a00 }}" />
{%- endblock checkbox_widget -%}
```

And then, in my form template:

```
{% form_theme formulario 'form/fields.html.twig' %}
```